# Should we allow questions on ctags / cscope

Tags: discussion, scope

Ctags / Cscope are very popular frameworks that are utilized in VIM.
Should we allow questions regarding ctags/cscope ?

Answer (score 7):

If the problem is with using ctags or cscope in Vim, sure. [Exuberant Ctags - Duplicate tags problem](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/5963/205) is a good example: the discussion in the comments involve Vim configuration.

If the question is purely about ctags or cscope usage, without Vim entering the picture, then, of course, nope.

Comment: More general, I would say that almost any "*X* and Vim"-question is on-topic.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, almost, but probably not "How can I use ctags in Eclipse the way I'm used to doing in Vim?"  :)

Comment: @Wildcard No. Obviously not every question with "Vim" in the title is on-topic.

Comment: Though what if you're using the [eclim](http://eclim.org/) plugin or similar? ;)

Comment: @WayneWerner If you're using eclim, why would you be using ctags in Eclipse and not Vim directly?

Answer (score 0):

`:helpgrep cscope` yields 316 results and `:helpgrep ctags` yields 189 result in my vim build. These programs seem to be important in vim, so 'we' should allow question on ctags/cscope

Comment: Are you saying we should allow *any* questions on ctags and cscope?

Comment: why not? I don't know anyone who uses cscope without vim.

Comment: @stdcall A bunch of people use emacs with cscope: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CScopeAndEmacs Indeed, the prof who introduced me to cscope exclusively used emacs in his demos.

Comment: that's true.  and there's also an emacs stackexchange beta site.  I think that the question should be eligible there too

Comment: @stdcall Which question? (BTW, [emacs.se] graduated.)

Comment: question about cscope.

Comment: @stdcall sure, they'd allow it, if you were asking about using cscope with emacs. A question about just cscope (or ctags, for that matter) doesn't belong here or there.